# Flutter only renders hard-coded emojis.. dynamically constructed ones are displayed as plain text

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm creating an app that will display messages that are pulled from our Firebase database. Some of these messages have emojis in them, stored in this format: \udd25. This is how they are scraped from Instagram.

Dart requires these entities to be formatted like this: \u{dd25}. I've already created a function that dynamically adds these curly braces, but the problem is that these dynamically constructed entities are not rendered as the emoji as intended.

If I hard-code an emoji like this:

```
Text('\u{dd25}');
```

The emoji is displayed without any issues.

However, when I revert to my solution to reformat any potential emoji on Instagram:

```
var emoji = '\\u' + uniqueNumber; // Concatenation with '{dd25}', for example
Text(emoji);
```

...this renders the String representation of the entity rather than the actual emoji itself. Is there some way to 'force' Flutter to recognise that this concatenated String is an emoji and should be treated as such?

Many thanks.

I have tried using the substring function to remove the 'escaping' backslash from the variable that I had to use in concatenation, in case this was the issue, but this just displays the same String without the backslash: u{dd25}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `String.fromCharCode` (https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCode.html).

It's not possible to just concatenate something with \u, because that's a literal constructor, not a dynamic constructor.

So for example, these will do the same thing:

```
print('\u{dd25}');
print(String.fromCharCode(0xdd25));
```

except the latter can be a value read from a data stream.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the help and sorry for the delay in ticking your answer!

Comment: How would this work with multiple unicodes the create an emoji? e.g. "\ud83d\ude00" ?

Comment: I've tried to do `String.fromCharCodes(str.runes)` but still get back the original string literal e.g. \ud83d\ude00

Comment: @onesiumus Please check my answer it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67565694/3974530

Answer (score 3):

`\u2764` is unicode for "Heart" emoji. Assume this is fetched from database. Then you can store that in a variable and directly pass that variable in `Text` widget & it does render emoji.

```
String emojiCode = '\u2764'; // assume, we fetched from DB
Text(emojiCode);
```

**Complete Example**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String emojiCode = '\u2764';
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Text(emojiCode));
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried that method but I'm still getting the literal text of the emoji instead - I've even tried without any concatenation to see if that was the issue, and now I'm receiving some issue "Invalid argument(s): string is not well-formed UTF-16" instead. The string is "\u5344\udd25"

Comment: This also appears to be still hard coding the emoji value, just separating it to another variable.