# How to display Unicode Smiley from json response dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, unicode, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

How to display Unicode Smiley from json response dynamically in flutter. It's display properly when i declare string as a static but from dynamic response it's not display smiley properly.

**Static Declaration: (Working)**

```
child: Text("\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude0eThis is just test notification..\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\ude0e\ud83d\udcaf\ud83d\ude4c")
```

**Dynamic Response:**

```
"message":"\\ud83d\\ude4c Be Safe at your home \\ud83c\\udfe0",
```

When i'm parse and pass this response to Text then it's consider Unicode as a String and display as a string instead of Smiley Code is below to display text with smiley:

```
child: Text(_listData[index].message.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"))
```

Already go through this: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55634094/3974530) but it's only working when single unicode not working with multiple unicode.

Anyone worked with text along with unicode caracter display dynamically then please let me know.

Comment: The string you want to display does not actually contain a literal backslash at all; `\u1234` is a single character whose code point is (hex) 1234. If your back end produces these in escaped form, your code needs to unescape them. How exactly to do that is a common FAQ.

Comment: Hey @tripleee Thanks buddy issue resolved by hint given by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by using below code snippet.

```
  Client client = Client();
  final response = await client.get(Uri.parse('YOUR_API_URL'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"));
        }
```

Here we need to replace double backslash to single backslash and then decode JSON respone before set into Text like this we can display multiple unicode like this:

> final extractedData = json.decode(response.body.replaceAll("\\",
> "\"));

Hope this answer help to other

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate Good Solution I would give to unescape characters is this:
1st ->

```
  String s = "\\ud83d\\ude0e Be Safe at your home \\ud83c\\ude0e";

  String q = s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");
```

This would print and wont be able to escape characters:

```
\ud83d\ud83d Be Safe at your home \ud83c\ud83d
```

and above would be the output.

So what one can do is either unescape them while parsing or use:

```
String convertStringToUnicode(String content) {
  String regex = "\\u";
  int offset = content.indexOf(regex) + regex.length;
  while(offset > 1){
    int limit = offset + 4;
    String str = content.substring(offset, limit);
//     print(str);
    if(str!=null && str.isNotEmpty){
      String uni = String.fromCharCode(int.parse(str,radix:16));
 
   
      content = content.replaceFirst(regex+str,uni);
//       print(content);
      
    }
    offset = content.indexOf(regex) + regex.length;
//     print(offset);
  }
  return content;
  
}
```

This will replace and convert all the literals into unicode characters and result and output of emoji:

```
String k = convertStringToUnicode(q);
print(k);

 Be Safe at your home
```

That is above would be the output.
Note: above answer given would just work as good but this is just when you want to have an unescape function and don't need to use third-party libraries.

You can extend this using switch cases with multiple unescape solutions.

Comment: I didn't try but may be it's helpful to others. Thanks!

Comment: `\ud83d` is a high surrogate so `\ud83d\ud83d` is nothing. Please update your answer trying your code with a valid surrogate pair e.g.  `\ud83d\ude0e` which should give    `U+1F60E`  _SMILING FACE WITH SUNGLASSES_.

Comment: @JosefZ thank you a lot for mentioning. I have updated my answer and it works well for both cases.